# Entity framework one roundtrip

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I have large entity framework query that looks for and reads information about products. Yet-next-part of my query requires me to wrap everything in group by clausule, and db chokes on that (it has already 30 columns, then it needs to group by additional columns, ouch).
I found out that this is fast:

- insert search results into temporary table - insert into tmp, select * from (...)
- read data - select * from (...) join tmp (...)
- read join query - select * from (...) join tmp (...) group by (...)

The question is how to perform that with entity framework in one database roundtrip (multiple result sets), or speed up that query in some other way?

Atm I have (pseudocode):
select dataColumns, groupColumns from data
join searchResults
join groupData
group by groupColumns

Here is sample query:

http://pastebin.com/gtnvqXjS

(some things may be not correct because I had to remove sensitive information)

I need to group query marked by `-- *** Order By` comment.

Comment: You could try future queries: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries

Comment: Could you please post some code samples?

Comment: @Steve Looks awesome, I will try it if there's no other way.

Comment: @Darshana appended to main post